# How to get the value of input text embedded in select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html template, I have a set of options in a `<select>` tag. One particular option allows you to type in custom category name in the input text field.

Now once I click on the submit button, I am unable to fetch the value within the input field (if a value was entered in it).

Here are the HTML `<select>` and `<input>` field(s):

```
 {% for index in list %}

   <select name="browser" id="select_id{{index}}" onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value=='customOption'){toggleField(this,this.nextSibling); this.selectedIndex='0';}">

     <option value="0">---- select ----</option>
     <option value="customOption">[enter your own custom category]</option>
     <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
     <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
     <option value="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</option>

     <input name="browser" id="input_id{{index}}" type="text" disabled="disabled" onblur="if(this.value==''){toggleField(this,this.previousSibling);}">

    </select>

    <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON TO INVOKE add_category() javascript method -->

    <button type="button" onclick="add_category('select_id{{index}}', 'input_id{{index}}');">SUBMIT</button>

 {% endfor %}
```

In the `add_category()`, I simply want to display the selected/typed in category value as an alert message on the screen.

```
function add_category(select_id, input_id){
        if($("#"+select_id).val()=='0')
        {
            alert("Please select a valid category");
        }
        else if($("#"+select_id).val()=='customOption')
        {
            var i = $("#"+input_id).val();
            alert("INPUT CATEGORY: ", i);
        }
        else
        {
            var s = $("#"+select_id).val();
            alert("SELECTED CATEGORY: ", s);        
        }
    }
```

However, no value is returned in the input or selected category value.

Comment: Did you try removing the `disabled="disabled"` attribute from your text input?

Comment: are you getting the input field in select box??

Comment: A `<select>` element cannot have an `<input/>` element as a descendant

Comment: Please always proof-read your posts. This question was missing key information because `<html>` elements had disappeared - they need backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of the select using the below snippet , This would help you.

```
var mySelect = $('select[name=browser');
var conceptName = mySelect.find(":selected").text();
console.log(conceptName)
```

The Executable snippet is in the below code Pen URL
https://codepen.io/redhatvicky/pen/RdzEGW

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_category(select_id, input_id){
        if($("#"+select_id+"").val()=='0')
        {
            alert("Please select a valid category");
        }
        else if($("#"+select_id+"").val()=='customOption')
        {
            var i = $("#"+input_id+"").val();
            alert("INPUT CATEGORY: ,"+i);
        }
        else
        {
            var s = $("#"+select_id+"").val();
            alert("SELECTED CATEGORY: ,"+ s);        
        }
    }



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not even valid html, Chrome renders the input outside of the select.

Place the input outside of the select.

```html
<select>
  <option>Select</option>
  <input type="text">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

input inside select is not a valid html as Andrian said.
You have to create a custom dropdown with input inside, not using the default select but element like ul, li for example.